# Ways to specify current user's file paths

Tags: .net, file, path

I haven't been able to find an answer for this, I believe, because I don't really know how to ask the question.  My C# .net app needs to be able to specify something along the lines of %Windows% instead of C:\Windows in case the user is not using the C Drive for their windows installation.  Also, I need to be able to do the same for their user folder path ie. "C:\Users\%usrname%\Desktop"

I would love to just be able to build a string from this info, or just be able to use some kind of identify (like I did above) to just pass that entire string to the File class.

I'm pretty sure this is simply, I just don't know the right way to phrase it to get good Google results :P

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Enviroment.GetFolderPath(Enviroment.SpecialFolder)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx)

```
// Sample for the Environment.GetFolderPath method
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", 
                 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));
    }
}
/*
This example produces the following results:

GetFolderPath: C:\Users\user912447\Desktop
*/
```